# What is the most reliable way to call cudaMemcpy from multiple MPI processes?

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda, mpi

I am working on a library that does dynamic workload distribution for the solution of a differential equation using CUDA and MPI. I have a number of nodes that each have a NVIDIA GPU. Each node also has multiple processes, of course. The equation takes a certain number of inputs (6 in this example) and builds a solution that is represented as an array in global memory on the GPU.

My current strategy is to allocate the input data buffer on the **root process on each node**:

```
if (node_info.is_node_root_process)
{
    cudaMalloc(&gpu_input_buffer.u_buffer, totalsize);
    cudaMalloc(&gpu_input_buffer.v_buffer, totalsize);
}
```

Then, I want each process to individually call `cudaMemcpy` to copy the input data into the GPU global memory, each to a different location in this input buffer. This way, the input buffer is continuous in memory, and it is possible to achieve memory coalescence.

I understand that calling `cudaMemcpy` from multiple proceses (or threads), that the calls will be executed serially on the device. This is fine.

What I want to do is share the address that e.g. `gpu_input_buffer.u_buffer` points to to each process. This way, each process posesses an offset `process_gpu_io_offset` such that the data relevant to that process is simply `gpu_input_buffer.u_buffer + process_gpu_io_offset` to `gpu_input_buffer.u_buffer + process_gpu_io_offset + number_of_points - 1`.

I have read that it is taboo to share pointer values via MPI since virtual addressing is used, but since all the GPU data resides in a single memory space and since gpu_input_buffer.u_buffer is a device pointer, I think this should be fine.

Is this a reliable way to implement what I want?

EDIT: Based on the CUDA documentation:

> Any device memory pointer or event handle created by a host thread can
>   be directly referenced by any other thread within the same process. It
>   is not valid outside this process however, and therefore cannot be
>   directly referenced by threads belonging to a different process.

This means my original approach is invalid. As has been pointed out, the CUDA API has IPC memory handles for this purpose, but I cannot find any information about how to share this using MPI. The documentation for [cudaIpcMemHandle_t](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaIpcMemHandle__t.html#structcudaIpcMemHandle__t) is just:

> CUDA IPC memory handle

which does not give any information in support of what I need to do. It is posible to create an MPI derived type and communicate that but this requires that I know the members of cudaIpcMemHandle_t, which I do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CUDA Runtime API has specific support for sharing memory regions (and events) between processes on the same machine. Just use that!

Here's are example snippets (using my [modern-C++ wrappers for the CUDA Runtime API](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers))

Main process:

```
auto buffer = cuda::memory::device::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(totalsize);
gpu_input_buffer.u_buffer = buffer.get(); // because it's a smart pointer
auto handle_to_share = cuda::memory::ipc::export_(gpu_input_buffer.u_buffer);
do_some_MPI_magic_here_to_share_the_handle(handle_to_share);
```

Other processes:

```
auto shared_buffer_handle = do_some_MPI_magic_here_to_get_the_shared_handle();
auto full_raw_buffer = cuda::memory::ipc::import<unsigned char>(shared_buffer_handle);
auto my_part_of_the_raw_buffer = full_raw_buffer + process_gpu_io_offset;
```

Note: If you're very curious about exact layout of the handle type, here's an excerpt from CUDA's `driver_types.h`:

```
typedef __device_builtin__ struct __device_builtin__ cudaIpcMemHandle_st 
{
    char reserved[CUDA_IPC_HANDLE_SIZE];
} cudaIpcMemHandle_t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would need to take a long look at your wrappers but I want to keep the number of dependencies of my code to a minimum. Also, it is still ambiguous as to what should actually go on in `do_some_MPI_magic_here_to_share_the_handle`... As far as I know MPI transmissions are limited to the types specified in the `MPI_Datatype` enumeration so I am not too sure how I would go about sharing the handle. Is there a clean way to do this with the native CUDA runtime API?

Comment: @wvn: Underneath, the API calls are: `cudaIpcOpenMemHandle()` and `cudaIpcGetMemHandle()`. See the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html) about them.

Comment: I should also mention that a collaborator is restricted to using quite old versions of the standard libraries and so I cannot guarantee that this solution would be portable to his environment.

Comment: @wvn: My snippets are C++14, but I can make them C++11 if you like.

Comment: I will investigate a solution based on the IPC functions and document what I can find. If I cannot get it to work I will consider using your wrappers. Thanks!

Comment: As for your question about what actually goes into the MPI call - it's `cudaIpcMemHandle_t`. Probably a typedef'ed `void*` or something. You can look at its size and recast it if you need to.

Comment: @wvn: 1. Instead of saying "thanks", we upvote... 2. With the raw API, you simply malloc and export (getMemHandle) on the main process, and import (openMemHandle) on the other processes. It's just that you need to check everything for errors, and you need to remember to free on the main process.

Comment: I am still no closer than I was before. I'm using MPI and "import on the other processes" is exactly the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I'm not following. If you can send octets among processes, you can send CUDA IPC memory handles.

Comment: MPI needs to know the types, sizes, and displacements of the data in the struct. As far as I am aware, there is no general way to share a struct - see https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Type_create_struct.html

Comment: @wvn: It's just a bunch of octets. Also, even if it wasn't - just lie to MPI. It doesn't matter, it's processes on the same machine. Same padding, same byte order, same everything. And even if it did matter - the CUDA people took care of you; see edit.

Comment: The CUDA sample codes include an example of how to share a CUDA device memory allocation between processes using CUDA IPC, and not requiring MPI.